# Are baby centipedes poisonous like the adults?

Tags: zoology, development, invertebrates

I know that centipedes have an appendage called "*poison claw*".But I am not sure if the same is there in the baby centipedes and if its functional like that of the adults.

**So are baby centipedes poisonous like the adult?**